# ¿cómo almacenar el nombre de un usuario al momento de registrarse en Firebase web?

Tags: javascript, firebase, web

Estoy haciendo uso de Firebase para el almacenamiento de información de una aplicación web. Sucede que al momento de registrar un nuevo usuario en Firebase, este solo se almacena con el email y la contraseña por medio del método `createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)`. ¿Hay alguna manera en la cual pueda también almacenar al mismo tiempo el nombre de esa persona? Si se puede no solo el nombre, sino también otros tipos de datos del mismo usuario.

Sucede que para guardar el nombre de una persona o cualquier otro tipo de dato sin modificar las reglas de seguridad, primero se tiene que estar accedido. Yo encuentro eso muy restrictivo. Creo que Firebase debe tener una solución a ello. He estado investigando y me he leído en la documentación acerca del inicio de sesión anónimamente, y al parecer, usando este método se puede lograr lo que quiero. El problema es que si ese es el método para hacerlo, al parecer no tengo la capacidad para aplicarlo en mi caso.

Espero que puedan ayudarme. Gracias.

Comment: hay posibilidad de hacerlo desde el servidor? La otra alternativa como decis es hacer primero una sesión anónima y después agregarle el provider de mail en vez de crear el usuario.

Comment: Utiliza las Cloud Functions de Firebase.

Answer (score 3):

Con esta estructura guardas la `imagen, email, provider, uid,  displayName` y otros componentes predefinidos, pero también puedes hacer en tu base de datos un nodo con las características personalizadas que elijas y luego ligarla con tu `uid`.

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(correo, contra).then(function(user) {

                                      user.updateProfile({
                                   //aqui guardas los componentes
                                          displayName: username

                                      }).then(function() {
                                          alert();
                                      }, function(error) {
                                          swal(error);
                                      });        
                        }, function(error) {
                                      // Handle Errors here.
                                      var errorCode = error.code;
                                      var errorMessage = error.message;
                                      // [START_EXCLUDE]
                                      if (errorCode == 'auth/weak-password') {
                                          swal('La contraseña es muy corta');
                                      } else {
                                          swal(errorMessage);
                                      }
                                      // [END_EXCLUDE]
                        });
```